# Huge difference (>100ms) between the touchsceen input delay of short tapping and long pressing

Tags: gnome, touchscreen, xinput

The phenomenon can be seen in [this video](https://youtu.be/fOQGTKyJ55s) (hope YouTube does not compress videos much).
This video is a 30FPS video.
In the video, I touched the touchscreen for 3 times with a stylus
(which has the same effect as a finger
but it is easier to tell the time when the stylus hits the screen than a finger).
The touch event test is done on a webpage running in Chrome,
which spawns a white square whenever a touchstart event is fired.
The graphics update every 1/60 second, and the delay in monitor is also rather short,
so these delays are negligible if we consider the delay of touch input.
We can see in the video that

- if the touchscreen is tapped shortly (the 1st touch in the video),
  the touchstart event is fired 4 frames (~133ms) after the stylus actually hits the screen,
  so the input delay of touchstart is about 133ms if it is a short tap;
- if the touchscreen is pressed for a long time (the 3rd touch in the video),
  the touchstart event is fired 8 frames (~267ms) after the stylus actually hits the screen,
  so the input delay of touchstart is about 267ms if it is a long press.

Therefore, there is a huge difference between the input delay of a short tap and a long press, which is greater than 100ms.
This difference is huge enough to be visible in a 1.0x speed video and fatal when playing rhythm games
(as a reference, a typical radius of judgement window of perfect judgement in rhythm games is 50ms).

I believe this is a bug of GNOME because the difference in delay is not visible
when I check the input events by using commands like `evtest`, `xinput test`, `libinput debug-events`, etc. or when I test touch inputs in Weston (DRM backend).
I even guess this is not a bug but a feature,
but I would just like to disable the "feature" because it just ruins my experience of gaming with touchscreen.

Comment: FWIW, I believe I'm seeing this exact same issue. Thanks very much for the precise timing info! I'm not sure it's a gnome-specific issue though. I just tried KDE Plasma, and I think I'm getting similar latencies.